# Scientific word - beamer

Tags: beamer, scientific-workplace

I have always used latex. However now one of my co-author asked me to work with scientific word. I could not find any reference for it. What are the main differences? Is it free? can I use all the package I have been used in latex? What when I do a presentation in beamer? does it work the same?

Thanks

Ginu

Comment: scientific word is an editor that uses latex to do the typesetting, it is not free.

Comment: but can I take a tex file written for example in texstudio and compile it with scientific word?

Comment: I've never used it myself, but you can download a 30-day trial from http://www.mackichan.com/licensing.net/dnloadreq.aspx See also http://www.mackichan.com/index.html?techtalk/how/howimportlatex.html~mainFrame

Comment: Beware: Scientific Workplace hasn't been updated since version 5.5, which is at least six (and probably more) years old by now. It runs only on Windows machines. Many of the packages that come with SWP5.5 are seriously out of date by now, and many "newer" LaTeX packages (such as cleveref) are probably missing entirely in SWP5.5. If your co-author insists on continuing to work with SWP, you should insist on the following: Have your co-author save his/her tex files not in native SWP format but in "LaTeX" format. That way, you can import the files directly into LaTeX.

Comment: Also, and importantly, Scientific Word does not support `etex` extensions, which are in widespread use in a number of packages (e.g., anything that uses `etoolbox`).  The result is that there a lot of code won't compile under Scientific Workplace.

Comment: thanks everyone, just a random question still linked to scientific word and beamer. How do I include a button to jump from one slide to another?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it is solved in comments